# OpenOfficeXML and HTML written to spreadsheet's cells

Tags: c#, xml, excel, excelpackage

I have been trying to write html content into Excel spreadsheet's cells using  [ExcelPackage OpenOfficeXML](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) and c#.

I am getting errors stating that input string has an invalid token. Has anyone came across anything similar?

Saving html directly in Excel works OK.

I do not want to use html encoding as the content has to be in readable form.

Comment: Please include relevant code and FULL error messages to assist in the diagnosis of your problem.

Comment: any relevant HTML, too.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more of the specifics:

If you're using XML to create your spreadsheet, you should use CDATA tags for HTML content

```
  <someEntry> <![CDATA[ YOUR HTML HERE ]]> </someEntry>
```

In c# you can add CDATA. It is a type of element.

```
XmlCDataSection CData;
CData = doc.CreateCDataSection("<someNodeName><h1>blah</h1></someNodeName>");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
root.AppendChild(CData);
```

Otherwise, you probably need to escape quotes and double quotes \" \'

Or you can use System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape() to encode both single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping single quotes solved the problem - Replace("'", @"""");

Thank you all.

Comment: that's pretty poor form to take another answer, and then post your version of that answer to your own question.

Comment: It's all about solving problems and sharing your findings, right?

Comment: What if your HTML contained a backslash for some reason?